# How can i implement background process in asp.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net

i m developing a web application where i m sending email to selected candidate email id in Data grid. i m using using System.Net.Mail namespace in the application.when i send a mail to candidate then mail class return a response. so i want to impalement background   process in my web application and display a processing image until all mails sent successfully.Can any one help me to out this issue?

Comment: I suggest you to use async/await to asynchronomously process sending of email. Also you can use ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(YouMethodToSendEmails) method or Thread class. After completing you show popup with message about state of emails. Another thing you can do - create an enum with flags e.g.(Busy/Idle) and in your async method set this flag. Depending on it's state you can show loading pic.

Comment: hi  Igor Lozovsky. thank can u provide me a link which show a demo code for this

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to perform this action.

Simply create the AJAX modal popup in asp.net with loader (.gif) image and show it just before Send() method of SmtpClient. See below pseudo code:-

```
 SmtpClient mSmtpClient = new SmtpClient();
 modalPopUp.Show();
 mSmtpClient.Send(mMailMessage);
 modalPopUp.Close();
```

Note: Dont forget to close it in catch block also.

Comment: hi Mukesh Sakre thanks.its right but after sending mails it gives the response so how can i impletment background process

Comment: Dusan is right, this code will never work because the server won't return the Response to the client until is done executing everything, so essentially, the popup will never show.

Comment: see.. I just shown you a pseudo code/logic based on the question you asked. Just show modal popup before loop and end it after a loop. there is no big deal. And for this thing applying await/asynch would be a damage to system.

Comment: @MukeshSakre why It would be a damage?

Answer (score 0):

There are hundereds of ways. You can do this via ajax.

- take a div with the gif image.
- hide this div initailly
- when u hit the submit button, show this div
- in the background(in you cs code), implement the mail sending.
- after all the mails have been sent and u get the response, hide the div again.

Here is simple code in the front end to show the progress. In the back end in your asp.net page do the mail sending stuff...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#click").click(function () {
        $("#loader").show();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/SendMails/',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (msg) {
                $("#loader").hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>

<div id="1"></div>
<input type="submit" id="click" value="Click" />

<div id="loader" style="display:none">
    Sending Mails....
    <img src="../../Images/ajax-loader.gif" />
</div>
```